# jquery mobile popup changing position on orientation change - iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, popup, css-position, screen-orientation

I have a jQuery Mobile popup window which opens when the app opens. On the initial load, I positioned the popup inside a div, which is centered at the bottom of the screen.

I would like this popup to reamin positioned near the bottom of the screen for any iPad orientation.  But when I turn the screen to portrait and then back to landscape, the popup moves to the center of the screen.

I have tried a few ways of resetting the position with jQuery, and I added some media query css, but nothing seems to work so far.  My code is below, thanks for any help.

html:

```html
<div id="popupContainer">
    <div data-role="popup" id="disclaimer" data-position-to="#popupContainer"  data-transition="fade" data-history="false">
        <p><span id="infoText">some texthere.</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
#popupContainer{
width: 450px;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
top:80%;
z-index: 10;
}
#disclaimer{
max-width: 450px;   
}
```

js:

```js
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( e ) {
if (window.orientation === 0 || window.orientation === 180)
{
    $("#disclaimer").popup( "reposition", { positionTo: "#popupContainer"});
        $("#popupContainer").css("top", "60%");
}
if (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90)
{
    $("#disclaimer").popup(  "reposition", {positionTo: "#popupContainer"});
    $("#popupContainer").css("top", "80%");

}
});
```

Comment: I just did a test in which I set the data-position-to to a div id and closed and re-opened the box on orientation change. Ends up going back to centre just like with yours. I think you'll need to specify x and y coordinates as proposed here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup Rather than just reposition to a popupContainer. Good luck with it anyway.

Comment: You might wanna see if the (native/vanilla) tooltip method described on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458970/popup-tooltip-position-in-jquerymobile cures your problem.