# Adding an interactive tooltip using jstree

Tags: tooltip, jstree

I am looking to add a tooltip/pop up next to a selected node in jstree. So the functionality I am looking for is when a node is clicked, this tooltip pops up to the right of the node.

I am thinking of using select_node.jstree for this:

```
$('#jstree').bind('select_node.jstree', function(e){
//Some tooltip code
    $("#jstree").append("<div class='tooltip'>I am a tooltip!</div>");
});
```

I know the select_node.jstree function works, I am just not sure about how to or where to add the tooltip.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I rarely use Javascript libraries or frameworks, but I did create a vanilla/native Javascript tooltip last week. Fully customizable and intuitive. Let me know if you're interested and I'll post the code.

Comment: I would love to see it. I'm sure I could learn alot from it. However, I will still need a jstree solution.

Comment: You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458970/popup-tooltip-position-in-jquerymobile.