# What is/are the alternative for 'title' for pattern attribute for input in HTML5?

Tags: regex, html, validation, input, title

I read in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) that using `title` is discouraged.

> **Note:** Relying on the title attribute alone is currently discouraged as many user agents do not expose the attribute in an accessible manner as required by this specification (e.g. requiring a pointing device such as a mouse to cause a tooltip to appear, which excludes keyboard-only users and touch-only users, such as anyone with a modern phone or tablet).

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="em" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" title="email format">
```

On mobile phones and tablets, it would be difficult to show a tooltip as one has to mousehover there.

What is/are the alternative(s) for using `title` for `pattern` attribute for `input` elements in HTML5?

Comment: I don't get your question. If it should be read as "What is/are the alternative(s) for using the `title` attribute for `input` elements in HTML5?" however, then the answer would be: custom tooltips with onmouseover and onclick events. If you're interested in that, see my answer to [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458970/popup-tooltip-position-in-jquerymobile/).

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Mobile or tablet user cannot have mouseover so I was asking for its alternative. The link you shared, helped me.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to title is placeholder, which is the gray text underneath an input element.

`<input placeholder="email format"/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/3dZ7Z/

Comment: I would like to use something apart from placeholder; for example if you want to user that the input should be in specific pattern like blood group for eg B+, here I have to show message to user that "Enter character and symbols" not in the input box(placeholder show it in input box), nearby input box, then?

Answer (score 0):

Tool tips might not be required for touchscreen devices like phones and tablets , an icon or on tap navigating to a new screen might help